# How do I search for multiple rows in one roundtrip to the database using SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Say I have a table called `Foo`, with two columns `Foo.first` and `Foo.second`.

I need to query the table for a 1000 combinations for `Foo.first` and `Foo.second`.  The naive way would be to loop through the combinations and do a 1000 `session.query(Foo).filter_by(first='abc', second='def').first()`.

However, I'd like to:

1. Submit all 1000 queries at once (we have a high latency to the
   database).
2. Ideally, get back a 1000 rows where each row is a `Foo`
   object or `None` (so, like a `first()` for each combination).

I'm sure there's a dead simple way to do this, but searching for various combinations of "batch", "query", "multiple" hasn't yielded satisfactory answers.

Comment: Are you looking for [tuple_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tuple_) ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh `tuple_` looks promising!  Would be great if we had positional `None`s (#2 in my question) so we don't make comparisons in Python.  Doesn't seem like `tuple_` supports that?

Comment: @IljaEverilä MySQL, but could use Postgres if there were a compelling need.

Comment: Could you give a small sample of rows and your expected query / output?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh So, don't think what I'm asking for is possible.  If you'd like to put your `tuple_` suggestion in an answer, I'll mark that as accepted.  It may seem trivial to you, but Google-ing with descriptions of what I was trying to do didn't lead me to `tuple_`.  (And looking at the API reference, I can see why!)  So, appreciate your help!

Comment: No worries. We'll just wait for an answer. In the mean time, I'd recommend you provide an example of input rows and the expected output.